# Laravel 5.2 login with external validation does not persist

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

to login I'm using laravel with an external validation of user credentials, after redirection data stored in Auth::user() doesn't persist and Auth::check() = false, but the session data saved correctly. After the login if I enter to the dashboard I 'm redirected to the login.
Routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/test', [
        'as' => 'test',
        function () {
            echo "Session------>";
            var_dump(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::get('user'));//Returns user data
            echo "User------>";
            var_dump(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user());// Returns null
            echo "\ncheck user.------->";
            var_dump(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::check());//Returns false
        }
    ]);
});
//Login
Route::group(['middleware' =>[ 'web']], function () {
    Route::get('/login',                    ['as' => 'login',           'uses' => 'AuthController@login']);
    Route::post('/login',                   ['as' => 'login',           'uses' => 'AuthController@loginpost']);

    Route::get('/logout',                    ['as' => 'logout',           'uses' => 'AuthController@logout']);
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'web']], function () {
    Route::get('/',                         ['as' => 'home',           'uses' => 'DashboardController@index']);
    //Dashboard
    Route::get("/dashboard",                ['as' => 'dashboard',       'uses' => 'DashboardController@index']);
}
```

AuthController.php

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
        return view('auth/login');
    }

    public function loginpost(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');
        $loginRequest = new LoginUserRequest($credentials['username'], md5($credentials['password']));
        $userRepo     = new MongoUserRepository();
        $service      = new GetUserByCredentialsService($userRepo, $loginRequest);
        $authUser     = $service->handle(new UserObjectPresenter());
        var_dump($authUser);
        if (isset($authUser)) {

            $us           = new User();
            $us->id       = $authUser->id;
            $us->email    = $authUser->email;
            $us->fullname = $authUser->fullname;
            Auth::login($us);
            $user = Auth::user();
            Session::put('user', $user);
            Session::save();
            echo "----saved user------";
            var_dump(Auth::user()); //Returns correct user data

            echo "Auth::check()->";
            var_dump(Auth::check()); //Returns true
            return redirect()->route('test');
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('login')->withInput()->withErrors(['Invalid email or password.']);
        }
    }
}
```

$service->handle(new UserObjectPresenter()); returns null or user data if login is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use Auth::attempt after login we you actually starting your session, otherwise Auth::check always returns false,
use following code

```
$userdata = array(
                      'email'     => Input::get('email'),
                      'password'  => Input::get('password')
                 ); 

                    if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
                                return view('dashboard');
                    }
```

Comment: I'm using an external validation to verify user data

Comment: use $request->username and $request->password, Input::get('email'), like this way

Comment: Auth::attempt($userdata) always returns false.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing an 'existing' user record to `Auth::login`. It has no id so it won't be able to be pulled back up on the next request.

Save that user record or use an existing one to pass to `Auth::login`